# Dynamically created iFrame is null when called from a page loaded by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created iframe made with regular javascript. It works great when its called from a static page by regular means, but when called from a page loaded by Jquery, I get a 'myIframe is null' error.

```
var link = 'http://www.blah.com'
var iframe='<iframe class="adframe" id="randomnumberhere" name="widget" src="#" width="300" height="250" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>';

document.write(iframe);
var myIframe=parent.document.getElementById("randomnumberhere");
myIframe.height=250;
myIframe.width=300;
myIframe.src=link;
myIframe.style.border="0px";
myIframe.style.padding="0px";
```

Comment: Do you have this thing loaded in a `$(function()` tag, or what? You simply added the jQuery library and this doesn't work anymore?

Comment: No. It's not in any function. That's the code. I just stuck it into a page that's called by JQuery. I use the code for ad placement. It'll create an iFrame wherever I place it.

Comment: question: you are calling `var myIframe=parent.document.getElementById("randomnumberhere");` but look like you are not in a child so should be `var myIframe=document.getElementById("randomnumberhere");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this one by adding a div with a unique id then append the iFrame to that div. It seems document.write can make the object, but appending to that element wasn't happening. The working code is below.

Have a dynamically created random number for the div in the html already there:

```
<div id="randomid"></div>
```

Then I made a function to append to that div with that specific id

```
function makeFrame(){
var link = 'http://blah.com'
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", link);
ifrm.style.width="300px";
ifrm.style.height="250px";
ifrm.style.border="0px";
ifrm.style.padding="0px";
document.getElementById('randomid').appendChild(ifrm);
}
makeFrame();
```

This will only work if the div is already on the page. I couldn't figure out a way to dynamically make the div and then append the iFrame to that div. Document.write made the div, but it couldn't append the iFrame to that element. Perhaps a delay would make it work? Below is what I tried, but didn't work.

```
var iDiv='<div id="randomid"></div>';
document.write(iDiv);
```